# REGEX - collapse any combination of non-alphanumeric symbols into a single "."

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I desire to collapse any combination of TWO OR MORE non-alphanumberic characters into a single "."

I already have one filter before this one, so that the only 3 such characters I need to worry about are "_", "-", and "."

This is what I came up with

```
OutNameNoExt:= RegExReplace(OutNameNoExt,"[\._-]+" , ".")
```

Sadly, it fails because I have only read the first 3 chapters of my regex book.

I would like to clean up a string such as this

```
98788._Interview__with_a_booger..876789_-_.avi
```

so that it would read

```
98788.Interview.with.a.booger.876789.avi
```

I also believe I would have to use a totally new operator so that the replacement happens with all occurrences and not just the first one, right?

Ready for the knowledge to flow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
OutNameNoExt:= RegExReplace(OutNameNoExt,"[^A-Za-z0-9]{2,}" , ".")
```

`[^A-Za-z0-9]` matches a non-alphanumeric character (`^` stands for negation in the context of a bracket expression); `{2,}` matches 2 or more characters from the previous expression. It is basically the same as `[^A-Za-z0-9][^A-Za-z0-9]+`.

Comment: That works, sir, and I see the curly braces operate with occurrences of patterns just as it does with occurrences of characters! Thanks!

Comment: But for the sake of education, could I have done it without using the excluding ^ symbol? Just by listing the three target characters inside the square brackets?

Comment: Ah, yes, you could. I thought you wanted to exclude more characters than just those three. Use `[._-]{2,}` instead, which is almost the expression you already had in the beginning. No need to escape `.` inside a bracket expression.

Comment: Well your first one worked great. This second one.. eh... actually added spaces back into the final string. Looks like the pros would use the first way.